# "package java.net.http does not exist" error on JDK9

Tags: java, java-9

I have a problem compiling simple blocking GET example from the HttpRequest JavaDoc:

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

import static java.net.http.HttpRequest.noBody;
import static java.net.http.HttpResponse.asString;

public class Http2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpResponse response = HttpRequest
                .create(new URI("http://www.infoq.com"))
                .body(noBody())
                .GET().response();
        int responseCode = response.statusCode();
        String responseBody = response.body(asString());

        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
}
```

I'm getting `package java.net.http does not exist` error when compiling using JDK 9:

```
{ jdk9 }  » /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk-9/bin/javac -d out/production -modulesourcepath org.example.module1/src/ -m org.example.module1

org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:6: error: package java.net.http does not exist
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
                    ^
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:7: error: package java.net.http does not exist
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
                    ^
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:9: error: package java.net.http does not exist
import static java.net.http.HttpRequest.noBody;
                           ^
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:9: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static java.net.http.HttpRequest.noBody;
^
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:10: error: package java.net.http does not exist
import static java.net.http.HttpResponse.asString;
                           ^
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:10: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static java.net.http.HttpResponse.asString;
^
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        HttpResponse response = HttpRequest
        ^
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class Http2
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        HttpResponse response = HttpRequest
                                ^
  symbol:   variable HttpRequest
  location: class Http2
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                .body(noBody())
                      ^
  symbol:   method noBody()
  location: class Http2
org.example.module1\src\org.example.module1\org\example\Http2.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        String responseBody = response.body(asString());
                                            ^
  symbol:   method asString()
  location: class Http2
10 errors
```

Same error occurs using command line and IntelliJ.

It is not a problem with my module because classes without java.net.http compiles and run without any problem.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your module definition, located (based on your package name) in `src/org/example/module-info.java`, you need to add the dependency to the `java.net.http` package, which is included in the `java.httpclient` module:

```
module org.example {
    requires java.httpclient;
}
```

You can find the list of JDK modules in the [module summary](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/ea/module-summary.html).

Comment: This is outdated and [replaced by the answer I believe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111760/1746118)

Answer (score 10):

Meanwhile, since build 149 of the jdk9, the classes

- `HttpClient`
- `HttpRequest`
- `HttpResponse`
- `WebSocket`

have been moved to the package `jdk.incubator.http`. They are part of the jigsaw module `jdk.incubator.httpclient`. See ticket [JDK-8170648](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8170648) for more details.

So you have to change your imports to `jdk.incubator.http.*`. Furthermore, you must include the module `jdk.incubator.httpclient` in your `module-info.java`.  When compiling and running your code, add the argument  `--add-modules=jdk.incubator.httpclient` to your invocation of the java and javac executables.

All classes related to the http client have been removed from jdk9. They are included as incubator features and are no longer part of the API. Hopefully, the new client will be part of jdk10.

Answer (score 1):

In JDK 11, the package is

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
```

And the module name is `java.net.http`

Comment: I just was doing some experiments in JDK 10, does it make sense to use JDK 11 right now before the official release? What do you think?

Comment: Not for prod. But if you are developing a library then yes given it is a LTS version and the 6 month cycle

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and this is how I resolved it.
In the gradle, I already had

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}
```

I added Gradle JVM as 11. This is in `Build, Exectution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle`
Additionally, I added this snippet in the build.gradle

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Plus I also made my module SDK as 11.

Let me know if this does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Gradle`

If you are using Gradle and IntelliJ it may be because the `Gradle JVM` setting is using a version below Java 11.

To change it in IntelliJ:

1. Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle`
2. Go to Gradle JVM setting on the right downside.
3. Change it to any of `Project SDK` or the Java 11 version.

`Maven`

If you are using Maven and IntelliJ it may be because the `JRE` setting in Maven is using a version below Java 11.

To change it in IntelliJ:

1. Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Maven` > `Runner`
2. Go to the JRE setting on the right.
3. Change it to any of `Project SDK` or the Java 11 version.