# Eclipse/java9-jigsaw: how to access javafx packages?

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, java-9, eclipse-neon

My context:

- 9-ea-113 (that is javafx now fully modularized, without jfrt.jar)
- eclipse-neon-M6 with the current beta support for java9 (running on java8, if that matters)
- win7

Something simple like

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class FirstApplication extends Application {
    //
}
```

doesn't compile because the javafx.xx packages are not found.

What to do?

Comment: Have you imported the module? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910746/package-java-net-http-does-not-exist-error-on-jdk9

Comment: Did you finally got that working? I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @assylias hmm .. I think that question is slightly different: I have no modules of my own, I'm compiling for java8

Comment: @mipa no, I gave up for now - can develop against java8 and move up to java9 later (using a patch layer)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .classpath file of the project and add the entry below - seems to work.

```
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
     <accessrules>
       <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="javafx/**"/>
     </accessrules>
  </classpathentry>
```

Comment: hmm .. the access rules are working for 8, but not for 9. Or what am I missing?

Comment: true - the setting compiles 8 only :-(