# Java 9 no class definition exception

Tags: java, java-9, java-http-client

So i want to try the http client

```
package com.company;

import jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client =  HttpClient.newHttpClient();

  }
}
```

And my module info looks like this

```
module com.company {
    requires jdk.incubator.httpclient;
}
```

But i get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient`

And I don't really understand why. My java version is "build 9-ea+ 169" and I use the latest version of IntelliJ idea (2017.1.3). I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911320/7940179) answer and it looks like I have to just add requirement into a file, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @QBrute the **module** `jdk.incubator.httpclient` contains the **package** `jdk.incubator.http`, see http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.incubator.httpclient-summary.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you're right. My bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

works fine for me if I use `--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient` as the start-up parameter.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
client.executor().execute(() -> System.out.println("Here")); // prints Here
```

If you say that your module requires it, does not mean it will be included; at it is not included by default.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there any way to automatically include modules?

Comment: @EmberTraveller Answer of Nicolai seems imply that when the module come out of incubation, you won't need `--add-modules`.

Comment: This answer is not correct - `--add-modules` [is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44049826/2525313). If it makes a difference whether it is added or not, then it just hides another error - most likely that the developer created module (in this case `com.company`) is not used on the module path.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for your comment. I had to delete my original one to fix an error I saw too late. I just reposted it.

Answer (score 10):

Either you or IntelliJ must have made a mistake. You are using an [incubator module](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/11), about which the documentation says:

> Incubator modules are part of the JDK run-time image produced by the standard JDK build. However, **incubator modules are not resolved by default for applications on the class path**. Applications on the class path must use the `--add-modules` command-line option to request that an incubator module be resolved. Applications developed as modules can specify `requires` or `requires transitive` dependences upon an incubator module directly.

I just confirmed that behavior on `java-9-ea+169`, i.e. I can compile and launch such a module (from the command line) without additional flags.

The fact that you do not get a compile error seems to indicate that IntelliJ correctly includes the module declaration in the compilation. The fact that you get a run-time error and that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043328/2525313) helped indicates that the JVM does not see the code you launch as a module.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problems

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient`

with `java-9-ea+173` and IntelliJ. I followed Eugenes and Nicolais advice to add `jdk.incubator.httpclient` explicitly to the module path via `--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient` in Run/Debug Configurations (on macOS: `Menu Bar -> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Configuration Tab -> VM Options -> --add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient`

[image]

After that everything worked fine. Of course you have to add the dependency into the `module-info.java` like this as said before:

```
module network {
    requires jdk.incubator.httpclient;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

With the latest IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 EAP 172.2953.9 , I don't need to put the `--add-modules` to the VM Options. It just works out of the box.

Comment: My advice was _not_ to add _jdk.incubator.httpclient_ with `--add-modules` because the documentation and command line experiments show it to be unnecessary. Could be that IntelliJ makes a mistake, though.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that. Anyway, the incubator module is loaded if a add the parameter. Maybe it is really an IntelliJ bug. I was also unable to load classes via ServiceLoader with IntelliJ. The just won't be found. On the command line it worked. Either IntelliJ is not yet ready or I am doing something wrong.