# NoClassDefFoundError while trying to use jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient in java in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, http2, jshell, java-http-client

Here is the code snippet that I use:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://www.google.com")).GET().build();
HttpResponse.BodyHandler responseBodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString();
HttpResponse response = client.send(request, responseBodyHandler);
System.out.println("Status code = " + response.statusCode());

String body = response.body().toString();
System.out.println(body);
```

Eclipse throws `NoClassDefFoundError` for HttpClient when I run the above code. But this functions perfectly when I use [jshell](/questions/tagged/jshell) with `--add-modules=jdk.incubator.httpclient`. What can be done so that the code is executed via Eclipse?

Comment: Does this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041698/java-9-no-class-definition-exception?

Comment: Yes. This helps. Thanks a lot for the lead :)

Comment: @ Kavitha Karunakaran  Please write an answer to your question, how did you adapt the answer in the given link  for eclipse environment.

Comment: @Steephen Thanks for the suggestion. I've added my answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @[Steephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144157/steephen) who helped me with a hint in the question comments. After viewing the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041698/java-9-no-class-definition-exception), I tried adding the following in Run Configurations for my sample project.

[image]

After that, the code ran smoothly without throwing NoClassDefFoundError.