# The jdk.incubator.httpclient module not found in Java11

Tags: java, http2, java-module, java-11

Using the [early access build for JDK/11](http://jdk.java.net/11/) to compile an [existing code based on Java-9](https://github.com/namannigam/jdk-http2) which was using a VM argument

```
--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient
```

to resolve the [HTTP/2 client incubator module](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/110)  now ends up with a compilation error

> Module not found: jdk.incubator.httpclient

Java version details :-

> ```
> java 11-ea 2018-09-25
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11-ea+11)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11-ea+11, mixed mode)
> ```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the [standardization of the HTTP Client API](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/321), the incubated APIs are now removed.

The module name and the package name of the standard API will be **`java.net.http`** which can now be used as -

```
module <yourModuleName> {
    requires java.net.http;
}
```

Also, adding to the tally, the applications, frameworks(like Maven, Gradle etc) or IDEs relying on the classpath ***would no more need to set*** the following command-line option to request the incubator module to be resolved:

```
--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient    OR      --add-modules java.net.http
```

Since being a *standard module* the `java.net.http` module shall be ***resolved by default***.

---

***Edit***:- I've jotted down the migration steps required for a transition from incubation to the standard implementation of the HTTP/2 client *@ [Medium](https://medium.com/@nigamnaman/http-2-client-incubation-to-standardisation-f4a5975e5833)*.

Comment: I would argue that the best option is through the module strategy since getting incubator features to work in IDEA with Gradle / Maven is always tricky. Thanks for the help!