# Java 9 HttpClient exception when using certain characters in URL query parameters

Tags: java, java-9, url-encoding, http2, java-http-client

Here is my sample code. The query is encoded to UTF-8:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .header("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/test?param1=test%C5%84"))
    .GET()
    .build();

HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
    .build()
    .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

After I run this example I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: char=324
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.Huffman.codeOf(Huffman.java:559)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.Huffman.lengthOf(Huffman.java:524)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.StringWriter.configure(StringWriter.java:79)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.StringWriter.configure(StringWriter.java:62)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.IndexNameValueWriter.value(IndexNameValueWriter.java:64)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.Encoder.literal(Encoder.java:422)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.Encoder.header(Encoder.java:245)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.hpack.Encoder.header(Encoder.java:198)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.encodeHeadersImpl(Http2Connection.java:927)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.encodeHeaders(Http2Connection.java:878)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.encodeHeaders(Http2Connection.java:951)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http2Connection.sendFrame(Http2Connection.java:984)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Stream.sendHeadersAsync(Stream.java:547)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Exchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl0$8(Exchange.java:322)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SSLFlowDelegate.setALPN(SSLFlowDelegate.java:164)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SSLFlowDelegate.access$200(SSLFlowDelegate.java:81)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:340)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:215)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler$TryEndDeferredCompleter.complete(SequentialScheduler.java:315)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.incoming(SSLFlowDelegate.java:242)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SubscriberWrapper.incomingCaller(SubscriberWrapper.java:388)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SubscriberWrapper.onNext(SubscriberWrapper.java:343)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SubscriberWrapper.onNext(SubscriberWrapper.java:58)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:739)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:171)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.internal.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:675)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:829)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:243)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:769)
at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:731)
```

`char=324` means decoded `ń` from query

When I read stack trace I found `jdk.incubator.http.Stream<T>` this method in the class:

```
private void setPseudoHeaderFields() {
    HttpHeadersImpl hdrs = requestPseudoHeaders;
    String method = request.method();
    hdrs.setHeader(":method", method);
    URI uri = request.uri();
    hdrs.setHeader(":scheme", uri.getScheme());
    // TODO: userinfo deprecated. Needs to be removed
    hdrs.setHeader(":authority", uri.getAuthority());
    // TODO: ensure header names beginning with : not in user headers
    String query = uri.getQuery();
    String path = uri.getPath();
    if (path == null || path.isEmpty()) {
        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            path = "*";
        } else {
            path = "/";
        }
    }
    if (query != null) {
        path += "?" + query;
    }
    hdrs.setHeader(":path", path);
}
```

In this method `uri.getQuery()` is used which gives us the decoded query and causes the above exception.

When I used `uri.getRawQuery()` in debug mode (which gave us the encoded query) everything went fine.

My question is: is that a bug or intentional usage? If it is not a bug, how do I avoid the exception?

Comment: `test%C5%84` maybe (extra %)? As in `"...?param=" + URLEncoder.encode("ń", "UTF-8")`

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. There should be `test%C5%84`, but in method `setPseudoHeaderFields()` I get    `...testń`, and future exception.

Comment: It seems that the Huffman compression uses a simplistic char to byte conversion à la ISO-8859-1. So to my very limited experience it seems a _bug_. You might revert to Base64: `"...?param1=" + Base64.getEncoder().encode("ń")` but then you need to decode the parameter yourself too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a bug:

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with jdk.incubator.httpclient when using some UTF-8 characters**
>   
>   Some UTF-8 characters like "š" can't be used with HttpClient. However
>   others like "å" can be.

See: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8201238

---

Java 9/10 HttpClient is **incubated**. It's **not production-ready**. It states so very clearly in the package name. As such, it's quite possible that it may contain bugs.

It will be released properly in Java 11 ([currently scheduled for release 25th September 2018](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/)) as part of [JEP 321](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/321).

Comment: Note: the HTTP Client API will be standardized in Java 11 and will be moved to a new package (and module) named `java.net.http`. ([JEP 321](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/321))

Comment: @Slaw I am so happy for this, finally a standard http client in the jdk itself!

Comment: You can plan to [migrate to Java-11 for using the **standardized `http` module.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122696/the-jdk-incubator-httpclient-module-not-found-in-java11). I can confirm that the [code in question](https://github.com/namannigam/jdk11-updates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/nullpointer/http/HttpBug8201238.java) works appropriately with JDK/11 (jdk-11-ea+17).