# Where is HttpRequest.BodyProcessor in Java10

Tags: java, java-9, http2, java-10

I'm currently leaning HTTP/2 Client in Java9~10 through [this](https://www.javagists.com/http2-client-java-9).

Java 9 does have `HttpRequest.BodyProcessor` interface while Java 10 does not have `HttpRequest.BodyProcessor`, but instead it does have `HttpRequest.BodyPublisher`. Both interfaces are similar.

**Why are Java change Interface's name?** I think backward compatibility ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`HttpClient` has been a part of an incubator module](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/110) with Java 9 and 10. So what one saw there was more of a prototyped work which though ideally shouldn't change much, yet doesn't guarantee the same.

From the incubator [JEP#Incubator Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/11):

> An incubating feature is an API of non-trivial size that is under
>   development for eventual inclusion in the Java SE Platform, or the
>   JDK, but is not yet sufficiently proven.

---

If you wish to use the ***standard module*** you can make use of it in Java 11, where it is named as [`java.net.http`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html). [*notice that its marked as since Java 11 and not 9 or 10*]

[The jdk.incubator.httpclient module not found in Java11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122696/the-jdk-incubator-httpclient-module-not-found-in-java11) could help you migrate the usage of `HttpClient` in Java 11 if you were already using that in Java9/10.

***Slightly Off-topic***: If you could compare the source code in the two JDK, you would find that there have been updates to the methods in the `BodyPublisher` as compared to its previous state, both in Java 10 as well as Java 11.

Comment: By the way, I am pretty sure that the changes corresponding to the incubator modules from Java version 9 to 10 were also published in some mailing list or doc, just not able to find it currently.