# Make the new JDK 11 java.net.http package visible in Netbeans 10

Tags: java-11, java-module, module-info, java-http-client, netbeans-10

After opening an existing Netbeans 8 project in Apache Netbeans 10, and setting the Java version to the newest JDK 11, Netbeans is still unable to resolve references to the new `java.net.http` package which includes improved HTTP handling with classes such as `HttpClient`, `HttpRequest`, and `HttpResponse`.

What needs to be done to make the new `java.net.http` package visible to the existing project in Apache Netbeans 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access http client module in Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122696/the-jdk-incubator-httpclient-module-not-found-in-java11), since reading the answer mostly emphasizes on the `java.xml` configuration in NetBeans while the remaining part suggests the same answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The jdk.incubator.httpclient module not found in Java11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122696/the-jdk-incubator-httpclient-module-not-found-in-java11)

Comment: I feel the two questions deal with different things: the question you link to is about moving from the incubator version of the new http package to the finished JDK 11 version; my question is about making the finished JDK 11 version visible to a Netbeans project which has had no knowledge of that package already. The two are similar, but I think my question is different enough to justify its existence, and so I'll leave this to the Stack Overflow community to decide whether it should remain open.

Comment: Alright. Makes sense, but honestly, the answer to me looks more diverged towards creating a modular project in Netbeans for the first time rather than including http client on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the new `java.net.http` package visible to your project, you'll need to configure your project so that it includes the module name "java.net.http" (found at the top of the [Javadoc page for the package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html)).

The existing Java project imported from Netbeans 8 will not have any knowledge of the module system introduced in Java 9, so initially you'll have no way to add a module requirement. To fix this, right-click on your Java project in Apache Netbeans 10 and then select "New" and then "Java Module Info...". In the dialog which appears, check the details and click the "Next" button and then confirm that you're happy to move entries out of the classpath and into the modulepath if offered. You'll now find a new file "module-info.java" in the default package of your project (under "Source Packages"/"<default package>").

Open the "module-info.java" file and then check your project for error markers (the angry red circles on the file icon, showing that the file contains a parsing or compilation error). Open the files which report errors and you'll probably find that some of the import statements at the top of your Java files now report an error such as this:

> "Package javax.xml.stream is not visible:
>   (package javax.xml.stream is declared in module **java.xml** but module MyApplication does not read it)"

This error would mean that you'd need to add the following line to the `module MyApplication` definition (where "MyApplication" will be a name based on your own project) found within your "module-info.java" file:

```
requires java.xml;
```

Save that change and you should now see the specific error about `javax.xml.stream` disappear. Repeat this process until all of the visibility errors vanish from your project. (If your project doesn't use any non-core modules then you may not see any errors at all.)

Finally, once all other visibility errors are out of the way, add this line to your `module MyApplication` definition:

```
requires java.net.http;
```

Save that change, and now when editing your project code in Apache Netbeans IDE 10 you should be able to see and use the new `java.net.http` classes such as `HttpClient`.

Comment: Is this about `java.xml` or `java.net.http`?

Comment: It's about the process of resolving any visibility problems which will be introduced for the first time when adding a module-info.java file to a project. The java.xml module requirement is simply included as an example, and such errors would need to be fixed before adding the requirement for the new http module.

Comment: This is answer is wrong. You don't need to use the JPMS to use new Java 11 classes or packages.

Comment: True, @AleksandrDubinsky, but the way Netbeans handled the project (as a module), these steps were required in order to make the http package visible to the project module. Note that this advice was for Apache Netbeans 10, and the latest version is 12. So it's possible that the latest version would handle this differently.

Comment: @Bobulous Actually, Netbeans 10-11 handled non-JPMS projects just fine, but my Netbeans 12 installation is broken and showing weird JPMS warnings which is how I found this question.