# Upgrading Java 9 HttpClient code to Java 11: BodyProcessor and asString()

Tags: java, json, java-9, java-11, java-http-client

[I have a code base](https://github.com/Linus789/DeepLTranslator) which (apparently) works under `Java 9` but does not compile under `Java 11`. It uses the `jdk.incubator.httpclient` API and changing the module information according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122697/3764804) answer works for the most part but more than the package has changed.

The code I still have trouble fixing is the following:

```
private static JSONObject sendRequest(JSONObject json) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI(BASE_URL))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .timeout(TIMEOUT_DURATION)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyProcessor.fromString(json.toString()))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString());
    String jsonResponse = httpResponse.body();

    return new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
}
```

The compilation errors are:

```
Error:(205, 94) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method asString()
  location: interface java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler
Error:(202, 34) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable BodyProcessor
  location: class java.net.http.HttpRequest
```

How can I transform the code into an equivalent `Java 11` version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you need [`HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html) as a replacement for `HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString()` and [`HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofString(java.lang.String)) as a replacement for `HttpRequest.BodyProcessor.fromString(String)`. (Old Java 9 docs, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandler.html#asString--).)

Your code would then look like

```
private static JSONObject sendRequest(JSONObject json) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI(BASE_URL))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .timeout(TIMEOUT_DURATION)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json.toString()))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    String jsonResponse = httpResponse.body();

    return new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
}
```