# Gradle build can't find the package 'java.net.http' and 'java.net.http.HttpResponse' and 'java.net.http.HttpRequest'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

**Currently I'm building an app running with kotlin and jetpack compose, but I have an error that I can't import 'java.net.http' and 'java.net.http.HttpResponse' and 'java.net.http.HttpRequest'**

[image]

And below are my entire project level gradle files:

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")

    id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("com.ncorti.ktfmt.gradle") version "0.10.0"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace 'com.tnmd.learningenglishapp'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tnmd.learningenglishapp"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

ktfmt {
    googleStyle()
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha06")
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.6.0-alpha05'
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.7.1")

    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.30.1")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.7.1'
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.47")

    //Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx")

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    //Stream SĐK
    implementation "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-compose:5.17.7"
    implementation "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-ui-components:5.17.13"

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'

    //Gson
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-java:1.5.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.5.0"
}
```

Can you help me if you find the problem or not, thank you very much

Comment: Looks like this kind of issue already answered check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910746/package-java-net-http-does-not-exist-error-on-jdk9)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is connected with the version of Java/JRE that exist in your system because the package "**java.net.http**" was included in Java 11 or up.

Try to download a new version of java from one of these sites [Oracle JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) or [Open JDK](https://openjdk.java.net/install/)

After installing the new version of Java check that Android Studio uses the correct one.

Comment: Yes i do, in gradle module is:
  `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }`

Comment: @TranDatK I'm not sure that the `java.net.http` API is available on Android. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69883204/6395627. Regardless, there are more Kotlin-friendly libraries out there for HTTP clients.

Comment: @TranDatK : Please check your machine for java version, if java available then uninstall it and install again for latest update. basically java.net.http  is updated in java 11 and your machine is not getting that package.

Comment: Thank you for  all for your help, let me try more